# Browser support for askerisk ( * ) wild card in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

Which browsers are able to understand and implement asterisk ( * ) in CSS properly? (By *'properly'* I actually meant -- *'as they are supposed to'*.)

Consider this CSS code for example:

```
pre .comment * {
  color: #800;
}
```

**EDIT:** I see now that it's called the '* selector' or 'universal selector'. Thanks a lot for the input. :)

Comment: Mind that the universal selector as it is called is a very expensive one and its use is discouraged. See `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Universal_selectors` and the chart on Steve Souders' article at `http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/`

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn : Oh, I meant 'as they are supposed to'. Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: @Matijs Thanks for the pointer. Will keep in mind, but I absolutely have to use it in my case. The example in my question is exactly that. I using that in my syntax highligher.

Comment: Okay, I also found a link that help -- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All major browsers do. Internet explorer supports it without bugs from 8.0.

See here:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector#compatibilitysection

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tab](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), all modern browsers should understand it...