# White space at top of page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have about 20 pixels of white space at the top of my page. I have inspected every element and nothing has padding or margin in this area. When I inspect the body element it does NOT include this space. When I inspect the html element is does include this space. Also if I delete

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

the white space goes away.

Here is my main layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @RenderSection("Css", false)
</head>

<body>
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please send the output html (View page source(Chrome))

Comment: Any particular browser?

Comment: Chrome is the browser I am using. I dumped the html here. Sorry for the poor formatting
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a050Lu76gd2Gu1JlxRsNlZmUjzNYYXiNLFMWlx8vlU4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Issue is also in IE 10 and FF

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Add a css reset to the top of your website style sheet, different browsers render some default margin and padding and perhaps external style sheets do something you are not aware of too, a css reset will just initialize a fresh palette so to speak:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

**UPDATE: Use the Universal Selector Instead:**
@Frank mentioned that you can use the Universal Selector: `*` instead of listing all the elements, and this selector looks like it is [cross browser compatible in all major browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988865/browser-support-for-askerisk-wild-card-in-css):

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: this makes the white space go away

Comment: You can achieve the same effect by using * to select all elements. Like `* { css }` This way you won't have to list every element.

Comment: @Frank, thanks I updated my answer with your recommendation, good one!

Comment: To be honest its not a good idea to use * as the selector.  Your asking the browser to add styles to things that don't need it such as the <script> tag, or add styles to inline elements that don't have anything set in the first place. 

This only serves to get the browser to do more work to display the page.  While this may be small, it will make things slower in general as there is more for the browser to think about.

Comment: Well at least selector both choices are there, hopefully people read the comments int he answer before making there final decision.

Comment: @bayedbest than you have an issue with the order of your styles sheets, trying putting this last

Comment: its removed the white sapce in my case. But the buttons are missing now which was working before

Comment: @RaviShankerReddy are you just a beginner at CSS? A CSS reset breaking your CSS for your buttons demonstrates you probably do not know what your CSS for your buttons is doing fully

Comment: Thanks for reply. The CSS reset is over-riding with my button CSS. Fixed now

Comment: If this solution does not work there can be another culprit. Look at my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55471272/6597265

Comment: Not only does this not work to remove the whitespace, it breaks all other CSS.

Comment: @Axelle lol, ya because your CSS is probably a mess

Comment: Using the rule `*, *::after, *::before { box-sizing: border-box; }` can also help to make elements behave in more of an expected fashion.

Answer (score 18):

If none of the other answers help, check if there is `margin-top` set on some of the (some levels below) nested DOM element(s).

It will be not recognizable when you inspect `body` element itself in the debugger. It will only be visible when you unfold several elements nested *down* in `body` element in Chrome Dev Tools elements debugger and check if there is one of them with `margin-top` set.

The below is the upper part of a site screen shot and the corresponding Chrome Dev Tools view when you inspect `body` tag.

No sign of top margin here and you have resetted all the browser-scpecific CSS properties as per answers above but that unwanted white space is still here.

[image: The unwanted white space above the body element]
[image: The corresponding debugger view]

The following is a view when you inspect the right nested element. It is clearly seen the orange'ish `top-margin` is set on it. This is the one that causes the white space on top of `body` element.

[image: Clearly visible top-margin]
[image]

On that found element replace `margin-top` with `padding-top` if you need space above it and yet not to leak it above the `body` tag.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but I just ran into this.  Sometimes your files are UTF-8 with a BOM at the start, and your template engine doesn't like that.  So when you include your template, you get another (invisible) BOM inserted into your page...

```
<body>{INVISIBLE BOM HERE}...</body>
```

This causes a gap at the start of your page, where the browser renders the BOM, but it looks invisible to you (and in the inspector, just shows up as whitespace/quotes.

Save your template files as UTF-8 without BOM, or change your template engine to correctly handle UTF8/BOM documents.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the css reset, I also added the following to the css of my `div` container and that fixed it.

```
position: relative;
top: -22px;
```

Answer (score 5):

This particular answer shows that h1 elements have an implicit margin-top that can cause the whitespace

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20021854/2129219

The suggestion to remove it is helpful, and certainly eye opening to how this is happening

```
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: Jeez I spent an hour stuck on this, thanks mate!

Comment: random extra note: this margin might be created by line-height but i have not verified that

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `height:100%` causes a scrollbar for me on Chrome.

Comment: @cyrf just add box-sizing property with border-box value e.g. box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons that you are getting white space as mentioned above. 
Suppose if you have empty div element with HTML **Entities** also cause the error. 
**Example**

```
<div class="sample">&nbsp;</div>
```

Remove HTML Entities

```
<div class="sample"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## overflow: auto

Using `overflow: auto` on the `<body>` tag is a cleaner solution and will work a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any webkit styles being applied to elements like ul, h4 etc. For me it was margin-before and after causing this.

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1.33em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1.33em;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Valentine Shi's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55471272/153422) half-worked for me.

I found that the browser itself was imposing a pointless and unwanted '20px margin' top and bottom of each page, hidden in the print settings.

Chrome always defaults to "margins: default" when printing. But they aren't 'default'. They are "Google's unwanted overrides that change the margins to something else".

The downside: every time anyone prints they have to be taught to remove Google's 'default' - it doesn't save it.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can use one of the following:

**Answer1:** The * selector means, select all elements and set their margin and padding to 0.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

**Answer2:** Select the h1 element and set the margin top to zero.

```
h1{
    color:red;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for those who don't want to do a full reset on the default element margins.

To remove the top blank space caused by margins (the same blank space that disappears when fully resetting the margins of all page elements) it's necessary to remove all top margins contributing to the top blank space. This means that it's not an `h1` tag or any other specific tag that will do this, but the initial tags with margins that provide content on the top of the screen (doesn't matter how nested, how far from the beginning of the document and how many different tags).

Here is an example where the two contributing tags to the top margin are the `body` tag and the first `p` tag (nested within the `header` tag). In the document, there's a `h1`, but it does not contribute to the top margin. Both tags were given the class `screen-start`, with the top margin set to zero, so the top blank space disappears.

Similarly, the `screen-end` class to remove bottom margin is also used and both the `body` tag and the last `p` tag require it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      .screen-start { margin-block-start: 0; }
      .screen-end { margin-block-end: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="screen-start screen-end">
    <header>
      <p class="screen-start">This is the header.</p>
    <main>
      <h1>Title again</h1>
      <p>This is the most page of the pages.</p>
      <article>
        <h2>Article 1</h2>
        <p>This is the first of the articles.</p>
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <h3>Footer header</h3>
      <p class="screen-end">This is the footer.</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

I Just put CSS in my `<div>` now working in code

```css
position: relative; top: -22px;
```