# Extra white space at the top of my page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I just noticed there there is this unexplained white space at the top and bottom of my page. I search through some post and they told me to make sure I used UTF-8 encoding without BOM and I tried that and it made no difference. If anyone would be willing to look at it the url is [url](http://server1.absolutez.com)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default spacing (margin) on the `<h1>` element is causing the top spacing. Add this in your css.

```
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a space.. There is a button on the top right corner.

Remove this source from your HTML code

```
    <div id="escapeButton">
        <button> <a href="http://google.com" title="escape">Escape</a> </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is not the button which is causing the space. Check the CSS, it has a `fixed` positioning ...

Answer (score 1):

add this on first line of css

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this problem and used this in the first line of my CSS file:

```
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

You can also add `margin-top: -10px;` if there are still problems.

Answer (score 0):

If setting `h1 { margin-top: 0px }` works, maybe you encounter the `collapsing margins` problem.

You can know more in [margin-top in a nested div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890354/margin-top-in-a-nested-div)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, a div with style like this

```
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
```

make an extra white space on top